# Error while returning multiple ResulSets from a stored procedure in MySQL

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

Here's shortened script of my stored procedure:

```
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS `GetVehicleDetails`;
DELIMITER //
CREATE PROCEDURE `GetVehicleDetails`(
    IN `inRefNo` VARCHAR(30) COLLATE utf8mb4_general_ci,
    IN `inSurveyType` VARCHAR(20) COLLATE utf8mb4_general_ci
)
BEGIN
DECLARE vehicleTypeID VARCHAR(2);
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS = OFF;
SELECT * FROM vehicle_details V
    LEFT JOIN vehicle_types VT ON VT.TypeID = V.VehicleType
    LEFT JOIN vehicle_makes VM ON VM.TypeID = V.VehicleType AND VM.MakeID = V.VehicleMake
    LEFT JOIN vehicle_models VD 
        ON VD.TypeID = V.VehicleType AND VD.MakeID = V.VehicleMake AND VD.ModelID = V.VehicleModel
    LEFT JOIN vehicle_variants VV
        ON VV.TypeID = V.VehicleType
        AND VV.MakeID = V.VehicleMake
        AND VV.ModelID = V.VehicleModel
        AND VV.VariantID = V.VehicleVariant
    LEFT JOIN vehicle_body_types VB ON VB.BodyTypeID = V.TypeOfBody
    LEFT JOIN vehicle_info_preinspection VP ON VP.RefNo = inRefNo
    LEFT JOIN fuel_types F ON F.FuelTypeID = VP.Fuel
WHERE V.RefNo = inRefNo;

# Fetch Vehicle Type 
SELECT VehicleType INTO vehicleTypeID FROM vehicle_details WHERE RefNo = inRefNo;
# Get details of body parts
IF vehicleTypeID = 1 THEN /* Personal Car */
    SELECT * FROM body_parts_personal_car WHERE RefNo = inRefNo;
    /*IF inSurveyType = 'preinspection' THEN
        SELECT * FROM accessories_personal_car WHERE RefNo = inRefNo;
    END IF;*/
ELSEIF vehicleTypeID = 4 THEN /* 2 Wheeler */
    SELECT * FROM body_parts_2_wheeler WHERE RefNo = inRefNo;
ELSE
    SELECT * FROM body_parts_commercial_vehicle WHERE RefNo = inRefNo;
END IF;
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS = ON;
END//
DELIMITER ;
```

Now, while executing the stored procedure with this statement:

```
CALL GetVehicleDetails('some ref no', 'interim-survey');
```

an error is being thrown:

> Static analysis:
>   1 errors were found during analysis.
>   Missing expression. (near "ON" at position 25)
>   SQL query: Edit Edit
>   SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS = ON;
>   MySQL said: Documentation
>   2014 - Commands out of sync; you can't run this command now

I have noticed that the stored procedure is throwing on second `SELECT` statement -

```
SELECT * FROM body_parts_personal_car WHERE RefNo = inRefNo;
```

in my case. Even if I write `SELECT Now();` or `SELECT vehicleTypeID;` before it, the stored procedure throws the same error. If I comment this SELECT statement out, the stored procedure WORKS.

The same stored procedure works on localhost perfectly. I am using phpMyAdmin on remote server to maintain my database.

Any help please?

EDIT: I am receiving same problem in all stored procedures which have multiple `SELECT` statements to be returned back as ResultSet.

And, if I click **Execute** from the list of stored procedures in phpMyAdmin, the stored procedure executes. But if I invoke the stored procedure with `CALL <proc_name()>;`, the above error is displayed.

Comment: If I run `CALL GetVehicleDetails('some ref no', 'interim-survey');` from HeidiSQL on remote server, it does return  results as expected. But if I run the same from a PHP script it throws error **Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted....**.

Comment: How many rows does the procedure return in total? Bit hard to comment the PHP script as it is not included in the question, but sounds that either the procedure returns more rows than your PHP script can handle or that there is a bug in the script that causes infinite loop and the PHP runs out of memory due to that. And please, do not move the comments around.

Comment: One row exactly from each SELECT query.

Comment: @slaakso The problem is perhaps with proc only as the PHP script is a simple database access call with returns result in the form of an object.

Comment: The procedure is ok. You just need to handle multiple result sets in the script.

Comment: As I said, the proc works fine in my PHP script on localhost.

Comment: May be one issue - my shared hosting account has given me 128MB memory.

Comment: 128MB is plenty for 2 rows of data. As said, your original problem came from the fact that you tried to use phpMyAdmin for task that it does not support (multiple result sets). Cannot help you with the out of memory error as you have not shown the code.

Comment: My database access code is very lengthy to write here. In brief, I am using PHP PDO for database access. Here is the excerpt of the code, if you know PDO - `$stmt = $this->pdo->prepare($query);`, `$stmt->execute();` and `$result = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_CLASS, $class_name);`.

Comment: You need to use $stmt->nextRowset() in order to handle multiple result sets. See https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.nextrowset.php.

Comment: You say "works fine in my PHP script"; let's see the code that pulls back the resultsets.

Answer (score 2):

The "Commands out of sync" error usually indicates the client side error (results from the previous result set have not been processed and remain in the buffer).

If you are running the procedure from the phpMyAdmin, note that phpMyAdmin does not know to handle procedures returning multiple result sets. Try to run the command from MySQL command prompt and see if you get any errors.

The procedure itself looks ok, apart from unnecessary `SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS`-commands (the procedure does not do any update/insert).

Comment: One row exactly from each SELECT query.

Comment: And the PHP script is your own? Mabye you should check the script.

Answer (score 0):

There problem was with one or more of tables involved in the procedure. Some queries and procedure calls inside a procedure were giving errors as "illegal mix of collations xxxxxxxx". I had to set COLLATIONS of all **char/varchar/enum** fields of tables and parameters of procedures giving errors to **utf8mb4_general_ci**.